# Unable to get EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext() in Unity

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

As per the tittle, I am unable to get the `EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext()` inside an Android Java class. More precisely, the returned context is equal to `EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT`.

My interpretation is that the code is called from the main Unity thread yet the code is not able to get the OpenGL context.

Multithreaded rendering is disabled. The project is a Unity project exported to Android. This C# code calls the Java `initSurface` method from an `Update` function of a `MonoBehavior`:

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (_camMonitorInstance == null)
        {
            // it is important to call this in update method. Single Threaded Rendering will run in UnityMain Thread
            InitAndroidSurface(camWidth, camHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            _camMonitorInstance.Call("updateSurfaceTexture");
        }
    }
```

This should ensure that it will be called from the UnityMain thread. I am very confident that the thread is `UnityMain` because in `updateSurfaceTexture` `Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("UnityMain")` is true.

```
private void initSurface() {
        unityContext = EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext();
        unityDisplay = EGL14.eglGetCurrentDisplay();
        unityDrawSurface = EGL14.eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL14.EGL_DRAW);
        unityReadSurface = EGL14.eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL14.EGL_READ);

        if (unityContext == EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT) {
            Log.e(TAG, "UnityEGLContext is invalid -> Most probably wrong thread");
        }

        EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(unityDisplay, unityDrawSurface, unityReadSurface, unityContext);

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, _unityTextureId);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        _surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(_unityTextureId);
        _surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(_textureWidth, _textureHeight);
        _surface = new Surface(_surfaceTexture);
        _surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
    }
```

UPDATE V1:

Everything works in emulators but not on real devices (Nougat 7.1 API level 25 and Android10 API level 29).

UPDATE V2, verbose logs:

```
2021-04-07 15:13:59.944 17317-17317/? I/m.MyCompany.MyGame: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-04-07 15:13:59.982 17317-17317/? E/m.MyCompany.MyGame: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-04-07 15:13:59.984 17317-17317/? I/m.MyCompany.MyGame: Reinit property: dalvik.vm.checkjni= false
2021-04-07 15:13:59.999 17317-17317/? W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:6900): avc: denied { read } for pid=17317 name="u:object_r:mmi_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1830 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mmi_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
2021-04-07 15:14:00.004 17317-17317/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "runtime.mmitest.isrunning"
2021-04-07 15:14:00.008 17317-17317/? D/ActivityThread: Attach thread to application
2021-04-07 15:14:00.270 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/m.MyCompany.MyGame: QarthPatchMonintor::Init
2021-04-07 15:14:00.270 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/m.MyCompany.MyGame: QarthPatchMonintor::StartWatch
2021-04-07 15:14:00.270 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/m.MyCompany.MyGame: QarthPatchMonintor::WatchPackage: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/
2021-04-07 15:14:00.270 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/m.MyCompany.MyGame: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/com.MyCompany.MyGame
2021-04-07 15:14:00.270 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/m.MyCompany.MyGame: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/all
2021-04-07 15:14:00.270 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/m.MyCompany.MyGame: QarthPatchMonintor::Run
2021-04-07 15:14:00.270 17317-17353/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/m.MyCompany.MyGame: QarthPatchMonintor::Reading
2021-04-07 15:14:00.270 17317-17353/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/m.MyCompany.MyGame: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent
2021-04-07 15:14:00.270 17317-17353/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/m.MyCompany.MyGame: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent before read
2021-04-07 15:14:00.273 17317-17336/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.MyCompany.MyGame#10245#256
2021-04-07 15:14:00.274 17317-17336/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.MyCompany.MyGame#10245#0
2021-04-07 15:14:00.284 17317-17336/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/AwareBitmapCacher: init processName:com.MyCompany.MyGame pid=17317 uid=10245
2021-04-07 15:14:00.296 17317-17354/com.MyCompany.MyGame E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@4f00392
2021-04-07 15:14:00.381 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame V/ActivityThread: callActivityOnCreate
2021-04-07 15:14:00.424 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/Mono: JNI_OnLoad called
2021-04-07 15:14:00.442 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame V/HwWidgetFactory: : successes to get AllImpl object and return....
2021-04-07 15:14:00.472 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/m.MyCompany.MyGame: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-04-07 15:14:00.473 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/m.MyCompany.MyGame: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-04-07 15:14:00.480 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{79b4c4c token=android.os.BinderProxy@f9fc86d {com.MyCompany.MyGame/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@f9fc86d
2021-04-07 15:14:00.487 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame V/AudioManager: getStreamVolume streamType: 3 volume: 2
2021-04-07 15:14:00.513 17317-17360/com.MyCompany.MyGame D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: onAttached, package=com.MyCompany.MyGame, windowType=1, mHiTouchRestricted=false
2021-04-07 15:14:00.535 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2021-04-07 15:14:00.537 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Not a typewriter
2021-04-07 15:14:00.547 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode jank list is null
2021-04-07 15:14:00.573 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/Unity: MemoryManager: Using 'Dynamic Heap' Allocator.
2021-04-07 15:14:00.576 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/m.MyCompany.MyGame: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-04-07 15:14:00.579 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/UnityMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:6901): avc: granted { write } for pid=17317 name="com.MyCompany.MyGame" dev="sdcardfs" ino=22707 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=dir
2021-04-07 15:14:00.579 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/UnityMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:6902): avc: granted { add_name } for pid=17317 name="7a32170c1f93ca2e897b288e8dae6264" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=dir
2021-04-07 15:14:00.579 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/UnityMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:6903): avc: granted { create } for pid=17317 name="7a32170c1f93ca2e897b288e8dae6264" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file
2021-04-07 15:14:00.579 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/UnityMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:6904): avc: granted { read write open } for pid=17317 path="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.MyCompany.MyGame/7a32170c1f93ca2e897b288e8dae6264" dev="sdcardfs" ino=41792 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=file
2021-04-07 15:14:00.579 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/UnityMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:6905): avc: granted { write } for pid=17317 name="com.MyCompany.MyGame" dev="sdcardfs" ino=22707 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=dir
2021-04-07 15:14:00.579 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/UnityMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:6906): avc: granted { write } for pid=17317 name="com.MyCompany.MyGame" dev="sdcardfs" ino=22707 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=dir
2021-04-07 15:14:00.579 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/UnityMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:6907): avc: granted { remove_name } for pid=17317 name="7a32170c1f93ca2e897b288e8dae6264" dev="sdcardfs" ino=41792 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=dir
2021-04-07 15:14:00.579 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/UnityMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:6908): avc: granted { rename } for pid=17317 name="7a32170c1f93ca2e897b288e8dae6264" dev="sdcardfs" ino=41792 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=file
2021-04-07 15:14:00.598 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/Unity: SystemInfo CPU = ARM64 FP ASIMD AES, Cores = 8, Memory = 3680mb
2021-04-07 15:14:00.598 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/Unity: SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf0), 4 little (mask: 0xf)
2021-04-07 15:14:00.599 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/Unity: ApplicationInfo com.MyCompany.MyGame version 0.0.1 build 691c9dd8-c42e-4505-93a5-a598f89c82d0
2021-04-07 15:14:00.599 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/Unity: Built from '2020.3/release' branch, Version '2020.3.2f1 (8fd9074bf66c)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a', Stripping 'Disabled'
2021-04-07 15:14:00.689 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/Unity: Company Name: MyCompany
2021-04-07 15:14:00.689 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/Unity: Product Name: MyGame
2021-04-07 15:14:00.699 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/iGraphics: [0020080c] pn: com.MyCompany.MyGame, p: 17317
2021-04-07 15:14:00.699 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/iGraphics: [0030050c] PV 10
2021-04-07 15:14:00.699 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/iGraphics: [0030050c] no element 'igfx'
2021-04-07 15:14:00.700 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/iGraphics: [0030050c] LoadCloudParams lib file success.
2021-04-07 15:14:00.701 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2021-04-07 15:14:00.710 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame D/AwareLog: Game opt is enable
2021-04-07 15:14:00.714 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2021-04-07 15:14:00.720 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame D/Unity:  GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_OES_texture_compression_astc GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d GL_EXT_texture_compression_astc_decode_mode GL_EXT_texture_compression_astc_decode_mode_rgb9e5 GL_KHR_debug GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
2021-04-07 15:14:00.720 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame D/Unity:  GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_texture_3D GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture2 GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_EXT_shader_pixel_local_storage GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil GL_ARM_mali_program_binary GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8 GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_RG8 GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp GL_OES_texture_border_clamp GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array GL_OES_sample_variables GL_OES_sample_shading GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks GL_OES_shader_io_blocks GL_EXT_tessellation_shader GL_OES_tessellation_shader GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box GL_OES_primitive_bounding_
2021-04-07 15:14:00.720 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame D/Unity: box GL_EXT_geometry_shader GL_OES_geometry_shader GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 GL_OES_gpu_shader5 GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_OES_texture_buffer GL_EXT_copy_image GL_OES_copy_image GL_EXT_shader_non_constant_global_initializers GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_YUV_target GL_OVR_multiview GL_OVR_multiview2 GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_KHR_robustness GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_EXT_protected_textures GL_EXT_buffer_storage GL_EXT_external_buffer GL_EXT_EGL_image_array
2021-04-07 15:14:00.734 17317-17401/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/SwappyDisplayManager: Starting looper thread
2021-04-07 15:14:00.764 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/libOpenSLES: Emulating old channel mask behavior (ignoring positional mask 0x3, using default mask 0x3 based on channel count of 2)
2021-04-07 15:14:00.774 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/AudioTrack: createTrack_l(0): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by server; frameCount 0 -> 1924
2021-04-07 15:14:00.940 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/MONO: Getting locale
2021-04-07 15:14:00.940 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/Mono: Locale en-MD
2021-04-07 15:14:01.184 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame V/AudioManager: getStreamVolume streamType: 3 volume: 2
2021-04-07 15:14:01.193 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame V/MediaRouter: Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
2021-04-07 15:14:01.587 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/UnityMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:6933): avc: granted { read } for pid=17317 name="8ed5ebc4840489a57fabfcc302306155" dev="sdcardfs" ino=41785 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=file
2021-04-07 15:14:01.982 17317-17330/com.MyCompany.MyGame I/m.MyCompany.MyGame: GcSupervisor: module enable:1
2021-04-07 15:14:03.533 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame V/AudioManager: getStreamVolume streamType: 3 volume: 2
2021-04-07 15:14:03.606 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame D/SensorManager: 0xb4e264c0 addFd fd=129
2021-04-07 15:14:03.703 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/Gralloc3: allocator 3.x is not supported
2021-04-07 15:14:04.031 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/UnityMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:6935): avc: granted { read } for pid=17317 name="7bd3b4937d9eddcae16dbb191d1a86db" dev="sdcardfs" ino=40438 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=file
2021-04-07 15:14:04.031 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/UnityMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:6936): avc: granted { read open } for pid=17317 path="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.MyCompany.MyGame/cache/UnityShaderCache/7bd3b4937d9eddcae16dbb191d1a86db" dev="sdcardfs" ino=40438 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=file
2021-04-07 15:14:04.035 17317-17317/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/UnityMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:6939): avc: granted { read } for pid=17317 name="bf713628390495c6ec745eec555d4a09" dev="sdcardfs" ino=41718 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c245,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=file
2021-04-07 15:14:04.068 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame E/MyCompany: Called from UnityMain
2021-04-07 15:14:04.068 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame W/OpenGLRenderer: [SurfaceTexture-34-17317-0] bindTextureImage: clearing GL error: 0x502
2021-04-07 15:14:04.069 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame E/OpenGLRenderer: [SurfaceTexture-34-17317-0] bindTextureImage: error binding external image: 0x502
2021-04-07 15:14:04.138 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during updateTexImage (see logcat for details)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during updateTexImage (see logcat for details)
        at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.nativeUpdateTexImage(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage(SurfaceTexture.java:248)
        at com.unity3d.player.CamMonitor.updateSurfaceTexture(CamMonitor.java:108)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.access$300(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:95)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:20)
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00096] in <2def9ed1a9834118bfbf55b64b4d3069>:0 
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallVoidMethod (System.IntPtr obj, System.IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x0000f] in <2def9ed1a9834118bfbf55
2021-04-07 15:14:04.144 17317-17357/com.MyCompany.MyGame E/MyCompany: Called from UnityMain
```

Comment: What's an API version of your real devices?

Comment: @Anatolii Nougat 7.1 (API level 25) and Android10 (API level 29). I will publish the exact error in a minute.

Comment: It's likely something with Unity. One person reported that this works while everyone else manages to run it only on emulators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was occurring because Unity was using Vulkan instead of OpenGLES all along. Disabling the Automatic Graphics API in the Player settings and dragging OpenGLES2 on top fixes the issue.